# "Portable Modules" work with the src version, but not the pre-built version

Tags: dojo

In order to use dojo 1.8 in conjunction with 1.6, I set up portable modules as described in the tutorial [Defining Modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/), under the sub heading "Using portable modules".

I've been using it with the source version of dojo, "dojo-release-1.8.3-src.zip", and it works just fine, but when I switch to the pre-built version, "dojo-release-1.8.3.zip", it throws 404 errors looking for dependencies:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/sb/javascript/lib/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo/parser.js     200 OK
GET http://localhost:8080/sb/javascript/lib/dojo-build-1.6.1/dojo/_base/url.js    404 Not Found
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/sb/javascript/lib/dojo-build-1.6.1/dojo/_base/url.js"

GET http://localhost:8080/sb/javascript/lib/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo/request.js    200 OK
GET http://localhost:8080/sb/javascript/lib/dojo-build-1.6.1/dojo/request/default.js     404 Not Found
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/sb/javascript/lib/dojo-build-1.6.1/dojo/request/default.js"
```

From the console it's clear that it's looking in the wrong place for the dependency file (looking in 'dojo-build-1.6.1' instead of 'dojo-release-1.8.3').  What I want to know is why?  All I did was swap the source version for the pre-built version.

Here is my configuration:

```
<script>
    var map18 = {dojo: "dojo18", dijit: "dijit18", dojox: "dojo18"};
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: false,
        parseOnLoad: true,  // in 1.8 they suggest setting to false and manually parsing when needed, but we're not set up that way at the moment
        packages: [
            {name: "dgrid", location: "../../dgrid/dgrid", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "xstyle", location: "../../dgrid/xstyle", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "put-selector", location: "../../dgrid/put-selector", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "modules", location: "../../modules", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "page", location: "../../page"},
            {name: "dojoc", location: "../../dojoc"},
            {name: "dojo18", location: "../../dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "dijit18", location: "../../dojo-release-1.8.3/dijit", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "dojox18", location: "../../dojo-release-1.8.3/dojox", packageMap: map18},
            {name: "dojo", location: "../../dojo-build-1.6.1/dojo", main: "dojo"},
            {name: "dijit", location: "../../dojo-build-1.6.1/dijit"},
            {name: "dojox", location: "../../dojo-build-1.6.1/dojox"}
        ],
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar (using both 1.8 and 1.6 source) and got a different error. I know it's not an answer to the question, but I'll paste it here in case it helps you find an answer.

This is my test page:

```
<script>
var location18 = "/dojo18";
var location16 = "/dojo16";
var map16 = { dojo: "dojo16", dijit: "dijit16", dojox: "dojox16" },
    dojoConfig = {
        packages: [
            { name: "dojo16", location: location16 + "/dojo", packageMap: map16 },
            { name: "dijit16", location: location16 + "/dijit", packageMap: map16 },
            { name: "dojox16", location: location16 + "/dojox", packageMap: map16 },
            { name: "dojo", location: location18 + "/dojo" },
            { name: "dijit", location: location18 + "/dijit" },
            { name: "dojox", location: location18 + "/dojox" }
        ]
    };
</script>
<script src="/dojo18/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojo/date"], function (date) {
    console.log("date18", date);
});
</script>
<script>
require(["dojo16/date"], function (date) {
    console.log("date16", date);
});
</script>
```

And the error I get seems to be related to loading two date modules. Not sure if Dojo can treat them separately, but I've not managed to do this.

[image: Error]

Comment: You might be able to access the the dojo16 date module by `dojo16.date`.  I don't know if you'd be able to access the 1.6 modules using the new `require` functions, as they were AMD.

Comment: Also I see that you load dojo 1.8 (`<script src="/dojo18/dojo/dojo.js"></script>`), but not dojo 1.6.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure I should import both. Your link - http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/ - doesn't mention script imports and I think I had trouble with duplicate `define` functions.